# phpmyadmin import/export blank section issue

Tags: phpmyadmin

So i have Xampp installed, php works fine, have several things setup, can login to phpmyadmin, setup the phpmyadmin database, pma user/pass etc. the issue i am having is when i click to import or export a database, all i get is a blank section. normally where a person would see to select data, choose if its an sql etc. here is a screenshot of what it looks like. there is an icon at the bottom i was able to click to open the console, that is it.

https://gyazo.com/c665c89827719e1e9c900b5b11160023

Comment: Can you tell us which XAMPP version you have and which phpMyAdmin version it includes? The phpMyAdmin version information is displayed on the main page.

Comment: phpmyadmin version 4.6.0 with xampp 5.6.19

Comment: Any hints in the webserver error log? Do the other features seem to work correctly? Please try clearing your browser cache to see if that helps.

Comment: Nothing in the log that I can see. Everything else in phpmyadmin works. So my only guess is there is a plugin missing or something not allowing foe it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your particular problem, but there have been few similar issues in 4.6.0 which are fixed in 4.6.2, so please upgrade:

- https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12159
- https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12248

If you have already upgraded phpMyAdmin from older version, it might be upgrading issue as well, there is known problem that prevents phpMyAdmin work when you don't delete old files prior unpacking new version, see [upgrading instructions](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#upgrading-from-an-older-version) for more details.